# Uninstall MacTeX 2010

Tags: installing, mactex

I'm about to upgrade to MacTeX 2011 by downloading the entire installer as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26001/upgrade-to-mactex-2011-without-redownloading-entire-distribution/26003#26003).

So how do I uninstall MacTeX 2010 so that my system is as clean as though I haven't actually installed it?

Answer (score 11):

First you install MacTex 2011. In the pref system, you can select your  TeX distribution. If you are happy with MacTeX 2011, you can search MacTeX 2010. In the finder you use the item "go to folder" with 'shift cmd G' and you type : /usr/local/texlive.

You see three folders :

1. 2010
2. 2011
3. texmf-local

You can now put the folder "2010" in the trash, you need to give your password at the system to do this !

Comment: You can also remove ~/Library/texlive/2010 if it exists